# How can I use the DeflateStream class on one line in a file?

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, deflate, deflatestream

I have a file which contains plaintext mixed in with some compressed text, for example:

```
Version 01
Maker SomeCompany

l 73
mark
h�22V0P���w�/�+Q0���L)�66□ // This line was compressed using DeflateZLib
endmark
```

It seems that Microsoft has a solution, the [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) class, but their examples show how to use it on an entire file, whereas I can't figure out how to just use it on one line in my file.

So far I have the following:

```
bool isDeflate = false;

using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\MyFile.dat", FileMode.Open)
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
     string line;
     while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         if (isDeflate)
         {
             if (line == "endmark")
             {
                 isDeflate = false;
             }
             else
             {
                 line = DeflateSomehow(line);
             }
         }

         if (line == "mark")
         {
             isDeflate = true;
         }

         Console.WriteLine(line);
     }
}

public string DeflateSomehow(string line)
{
    // How do I deflate just that string?
}
```

---

Since the file is not created by me (we're only reading it in), we have no control over its structure... but, I'm not tied down to the code I have right now. If I need to change more of it than simply figuring out how to implement the **DeflateSomehow** method, than I'm fine with that as well.

Comment: It's worth to note that there is an issue with the `DeflateStream` class, sort of. If someone used an RFC 1950 implementation, then you must skip the first two bytes. See this Microsoft Connect issue: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/97064/deflatestream-throws-exception-when-inflating-pdf-streams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deflate stream works on binary data. An arbitrary binary chunk in the middle of a text file is also known as: a corrupt text file. There is no sane way of decoding this:

- you can't read "lines", because there is no definition of a "line" when talking about binary data; any combination of CR/LF/CRLF/etc could occur completely by random in the binary data
- you can't read a "string line", because that suggests you are running the data through an `Encoding`; but since this *isn't text data*, again: that will simply give you gibberish that cannot be processed (it will have lost data when reading)

Now, the second of these two problems is solvable by reading via the `Stream` API rather than the `StreamReader` API, so that you are only ever reading *binary*; you would then need to look for the line endings yourself, using an `Encoding` to probe what you can (noting that this isn't as simple as it sounds if you are using multi/variable-byte encodings such as UTF-8).

However, the first of these two problems is inherently *not solvable* by itself. To do this reliably, you would need some kind of binary framing protocol - which again, does not exist in a text file. It looks like the example is using "mark" and "endmark" - again, there is technically a chance that these would occur at random, but you'll *probably* get away with it for the 99.999% case. The trick, then, would be to read the entire file manually using `Stream` and `Encoding`, looking for "mark" and "endmark" - and stripping the bits that are encoded as text from the bits that are compressed data. Then run the encoded-as-text piece through the correct `Encoding`.

However! At the point when you are reading binary, then it is simple: you simply buffer the right amount (using whatever framing/sentinel protocol the data is written in), and use something like:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using(var inflate = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    // now read from 'inflate'
}
```

---

With the addition of the `l 73` marker, and the information that it is ASCII, it becomes a little more viable.

This won't work *for me* because the data here on SO is already corrupted (posting binary as text does that), but *basically* something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var file = File.OpenRead("my.txt"))
        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            string line;
            while ((line = ReadToCRLF(file, buffer)) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                if (line == "mark" && lines.Count >= 2)
                {
                    var match = Regex.Match(lines[lines.Count - 2], "^l ([0-9]+)$");
                    int bytes;
                    if (match.Success && int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out bytes))
                    {
                        ReadBytes(file, buffer, bytes);
                        string inflated = Inflate(buffer);
                        lines.Add(inflated); // or something similar
                        Console.WriteLine(inflated);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    static string Inflate(Stream source)
    {
        using (var deflate = new DeflateStream(source, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(deflate, Encoding.ASCII))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    static void ReadBytes(Stream source, MemoryStream buffer, int count)
    {
        buffer.SetLength(count);
        int read, offset = 0;
        while (count > 0 && (read = source.Read(buffer.GetBuffer(), offset, count)) > 0)
        {
            count -= read;
            offset += read;
        }
        if (count != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
        buffer.Position = 0;
    }
    static string ReadToCRLF(Stream source, MemoryStream buffer)
    {
        buffer.SetLength(0);
        int next;
        bool wasCr = false;
        while ((next = source.ReadByte()) >= 0)
        {
            if(next == 10 && wasCr) { // CRLF
                // end of line (minus the CR)
                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                     buffer.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)buffer.Length - 1);
            }
            buffer.WriteByte((byte)next);
            wasCr = next == 13;
        }
        // end of file
        if (buffer.Length == 0) return null;
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)buffer.Length);

    }
}
```

Comment: Its possible to overcome these issues if the binary data is prefixed with the number of bytes, fixed length, or the length is stored elsewhere.

Comment: You're correct. I talked to the provider of the file and they said that the line starting with l is a marker for the length of the binary. I reduced down my example of the file not thinking that `l 73` was important, but it turns out it is. So, I know that the garbled text is 73 bytes that cannot be converted into a line.

Comment: @Ashigore which is why I mentioned framing protocols

Comment: @michael can they tell you what the encoding is for the non-binary portion? is it ASCII? or something trickier? The `l 73` does solve the "when does it end" problem, indeed.

Comment: @MarcGravell: ASCII, they advised us that when inflated it is readable ASCII text.

Comment: I'll try it out and see if that works, thank you so much for the help. It's much clearer now what you mean about mixing text and binary.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I made a few minor adjustments to take into account CR, LF, or CRLF for the method, also I removed the entire `ReadBytes(file, buffer, bytes)` method as for some reason you made it reset the stream position back to 0, causing an infinite loop. But, overall this works good. The DeflateStream couldn't actually get valid data to deflate, so I think they used some incorrect compression or something. I'm having them send me over their compression/decompression algorithms to look at. Overall, thank you for the general information.

Comment: @michael that should have been buffer.Position = 0 - my bad; that might fix the inflate too